# Open GL: multithreaded glFlushMappedBufferRange?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, graphics, vbo

I know that multi threaded OpenGL is a delicate topic and I am not trying here to render from multiple threads. I also do not try to create multiple contexts and share objects with share lists. I have a single context and I issue draw commands and gl state changes only from the main thread.

However, I am dynamically updating parts of a VBO in every frame. I only write to the VBO, I do not need to read it on the CPU side. I use glMapBufferRange so I can compute the changed data on the fly and don't need an additional copy (which would be created by the blocking glBufferSubData).

It works and now I would like to multi thread the the data update (since it needs to update a lot of vertices at steady 90 fps) and use a persistently mapped buffer (using GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT). This will require to issue glFlushMappedBufferRange whenever a worker thread finished updating parts of the mapped buffer.

Is it fine to call glFlushMappedBufferRange on a separate thread? The Ranges the different threads operate on do not overlap. Is there an overhead or implicit synchronisation involved in doing so?

Comment: Any OpenGL call needs a context. You would certainly need to create an extra context for the worker thread if you want to call `glFlushMappedBufferRange()` from it.

Comment: But you *can* pass the mapped pointer to the secondary thread and have read/write funtimes there all you want.  Just make sure to block the secondary thread from touching range you're flushing for the duration of the main-thread `glFlushMappedBufferRange()` call.

Answer (score 0):

No you *need* to call `glFlushMappedBufferRange` in the thread that does the openGL stuff.

To overcome this you have 2 options:

1. get the openGL context and make it current in the worker thread. Which means the openGL thread has to relinquish the context for it to work.
2. push the relevant range into a thread-safe queue and let the openGL thread pop each range from it and call `glFlushMappedBufferRange`.